Can not create and use token to use ACS for a teams user: "CallAgent must be created only with ACS token."
I am trying to follow two tutorials, both are working, still my use case gives an error.

first is how to get ACS token for a Teams user here (for the C# code jump directly within the tutorial here) (NOTE: My real use case is a web app, so I got the token slightly different way, but the token itself exactly the same content and issue)
second how to create a custom web application which uses @azure/communication-common
@azure/communication-react packages to participate in a teams call. here (See point 11.where I place my token in case you want the details)

The first seems to be working, I am logging with my teamuser@mytenant.com, and got the token:
(the guid 53b----b70 is my user id in the tenant))
{
  "skypeid": "orgid:53b*****-****-****-****-*********b70",
  "scp": 1024,
  "csi": "1715345005",
  "exp": 1715349008,
  "rgn": "emea",
  "tid": "937*****-****-****-****-*********7d1",
  "acsScope": "voip,chat",
  "resourceId": "871*****-****-****-****-*********86d",
  "aad_iat": "1715345005",
  "aad_uti": "E4*****************oAA",
  "aad_appid": "1fd5118e-2576-4263-8130-9503064c837a",// ACS Service Principal
  "iat": 1715345305
}

The second is also working, if I am using the generated (unverified user) Identity and Access Token values from my configured Communication Service page on the Azure portal.
Issue:
If I try to use the application in the second tutorial to join to the meeting as Teams user (teamuser@mytenant.com), and try to use the Identity 53b----b70, and the successfully generated token from the first tutoial above, I got the error message:

CallError: CallClient.createCallAgent: CallAgent must be created only
with ACS token

The error message hints that my portal generated token below which is has a "skypeid" which begins with acs: but the not working my Teams user token's skypeid starts with orgid:? But how can get such a token for my Teams user?
// portal generated token which is working, skypid starts with acs, 
// and in form of acs:{resourceId}_{randomuser-id}. 
// According to portal generated Identitiy which is the same with 8: prefix
{
  "skypeid": "acs:871*****-****-****-****-*********86d_000*****-****-****-****-*********fc1", 
  "scp": 1792,
  "csi": "1715344681",
  "exp": 1715431081,
  "rgn": "emea",
  "acsScope": "chat,voip",
  "resourceId": "871*****-****-****-****-*********86d",
  "resourceLocation": "europe",
  "iat": 1715344681
}


According to this changelog, you have to use TeamsCallAgent instead of CallAgent.
const userToken = '<ACCESS_TOKEN_FOR_MICROSOFT_365_IDENTITY>';
callClient = new CallClient();
const tokenCredential = new AzureCommunicationTokenCredential(userToken);
const teamsCallAgent = await callClient.createTeamsCallAgent(tokenCredential);


It this issue resolved with the code suggested by Greyx?

The token you obtained for your Teams user (teamuser@mytenant.com) is not an ACS token but rather an Azure AD token, which is why it's not working. The ACS token for a Teams user should start with acs: whereas an Azure AD token typically starts with orgid:. You need to exchange the Microsoft Entra user token for an ACS token using the Azure Communication Services Identity SDK. This process involves using your Communication Services resource to authenticate the request for exchanging the Microsoft Entra user token for an ACS token of a Teams user.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/manage-teams-identity?pivots=programming-language-csharp#step-3-exchange-the-microsoft-entra-access-token-of-the-teams-user-for-a-communication-identity-access-token

Also, you can use the az communication user-identity token get-for-teams-user command with the appropriate parameters to get the ACS token for your Teams user. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/communication/user-identity/token?view=azure-cli-latest

@Prasad-MSFT, please read the OP more carefully. The token I am describing is indeed a Teams token, and I am getting it via GetTokenForTeamsUserAsync
